# Can we set readonly property in category…?

Tags: ios, iphone, categories

I have the following code:

```
Student.h
@property(strong, nonatomic, readOnly) NSString *name;

Student.m
@property(strong, nonatomic, readWrite) NSString *name;
```

What happen if I tried to set name in Category(e.g. `Student+Details.h`)?
e.g.
    self.name = @"Rohit";

What if tried in other class, e.g.

```
StudentDetailsVC.m
Student *student = [[Student alloc] init];
student.name = @"Rohit";
```

Ignore Syntax error. I have typed manually here for explaining situation.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a compilation error and if you managed to convince the compiler to ignore that error (through the use of `#pragma`s or compiler options) then you'd get a runtime error (unknown selector) as the setter method would not exist.

However if you know the instance variable that backs the property, then you can set it directly.

Chances are it's called `_name`:

```
_name = @"Andy";
```

Comment: I wrote error free code and executed same. I got error in both cases. Then I added IBOutlet *UILabel instead of NSString. Code worked fine. how this happened? assume class have related .xib file

Comment: @120hit I've no idea.  Certainly setting a `UILabel` to `@"Andy"` will break for sure.